# do you think bitcoin futures exchanges (CBOE/CME) are a positive or negative for bitcoin price and why?

Tags: exchange-rate

do you think bitcoin futures exchanges (CBOE/CME) are a positive or negative for bitcoin price and why?

Answer (score 3):

I do not consider the Futures Exchanges to be a good thing.

I don't trust large institutional traders.  They can and will manipulate prices in their favor.  I believe they are currently running up the price artificially ahead of the start of Futures trading.

Once futures trading begins, they'll short BTC then dump it.  The price will plummet, and their shorts will make a fortune.  Then they'll trumpet how they were right all along about it being a bubble; a bubble of their own creation, burst to benefit them.

Comment: I hate conspiracy theories; however you might be right.  Futures are an almost perfect way to manipulate price.  Having said that, there may just be enough hodl'ers looking for a nice buying opportunity to effectively counter the issue.  In my opinion, its a good thing transactions take a long time to process because that should give humans (hodl'ers) a chance to react.

Comment: Pure speculation, and also this conspiracy theory is gaining so much traction, it'd be stupid for them to actually do it. So many shoe shiners think they know what instutional money is going to do but the truth is smart money won't make sense to dumb money.

Comment: Every answer would be pure speculation: No one can predict the future. So you're stating the obvious, then not offering any counter-point beyond saying that I'm "dumb money".